# How to instantiate a class from a different folder structure (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Using Rails 3.2 and ruby 1.9.3p0

I am trying out the gem delayed_job. I have created a file lib/mailing_job.rb in which I have class MailingJob.

In a controller under app/controllers/requests_controller.rb I am calling

`job = MailingJob.new(@request)`

but this is returning the error

```
uninitialized constant RequestsController::MailingJob
```

I think it is because I need a proper way of referencing a class under a different folder structure.

Any idea how I can isntantiate class MailingJob from a different file (class) in a different folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails 3 does not include the lib folder within the load path so your application does not know how to find the class.

You can modify `config/application.rb` and add a line to instruct rails to also look in the lib folder like so

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

Answer (score 1):

In an initializer (e.g. config/initializers/delayed_job.rb), do this (doesnt matter where)

```
require 'mailing_job'
```